# How can run app in NanoPC T3 with os android 7 ,that have access to UART?

Tags: android, uart

I have `NanoPC-T3` with OS Android 7 in the wiki page have old sample write in android SDK 17, and i can not run it in android SDK 29, any body have experience to work with that ??

I want to use UART3 or other serial port but i got the permission error, my app must have system permission to get data from RX,TX port on bard.